# T-SQL Find Values Between Min and Max at specific Index

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, max, case, min

I have a table with 2 values: MAC and ID.

One ID can have multiple MAC's. For Example:

[image]

I added a column Count, which counts the number of ID's:

[image]

My end goal is to have the MAC's split up like this:

[image]

I THINK I'm on the right track using case statements:

```
select count, ID,
MAC1 = case
when count >0 then min(MAC) end,
MAC2 = case 
when count = 2 then max(MAC) end,
MAC3 = case
when count = 3 then max(MAC) end,
MAC4 = case
when count = 4 then max(MAC) end from MACTABLE
```

But that obviously gives me results like this:

[image]

So my question is this: How do I get MAC2, MAC3, etc if the count is more than 2? Is there a selected index type function? Am I way overthinking this? The MAC's don't need to be in a specific order, that's just the best way that I could think to do this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'd get the max count and based off that number create your columns with a pivot.

Comment: @scsimon , I've heard of pivot's but never used one before. Would you be able to explain a bit further?

Comment: There are a lot of examples on pivot and dynamic pivot on SO but here is an example on how to get your column names to get you started http://rextester.com/NJOQ46585

Comment: I'd consider getting rid of that count column - it's something that can be easily calculated and it just contains duplicated data, wasting space. How many MACS can there be for any given ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE [MAC$] (
    [ID] int,
    [MAC] varchar(10)
)
INSERT [dbo].[MAC$] ([ID], [MAC]) VALUES (1, N'120034')
INSERT [dbo].[MAC$] ([ID], [MAC]) VALUES (1, N'567869')
INSERT [dbo].[MAC$] ([ID], [MAC]) VALUES (1, N'741AB00')
INSERT [dbo].[MAC$] ([ID], [MAC]) VALUES (2, N'185AZ1')
INSERT [dbo].[MAC$] ([ID], [MAC]) VALUES (2, N'FD8978')
INSERT [dbo].[MAC$] ([ID], [MAC]) VALUES (3, N'H85HLK')
GO
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT Id, CAST([Mac] as varchar(10)) as val, 'MAC_' + CAST(DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY Id, Mac) as varchar(10)) as namePivot FROM [Mac$] WHERE LEN(Mac)>0) as data
PIVOT (MAX(val) FOR namePivot in ([MAC_1],[MAC_2],[MAC_3],[MAC_4],[MAC_5])) as P
GROUP BY Id,[MAC_1],[MAC_2],[MAC_3],[MAC_4],[MAC_5]
```

Recommended way for expanding it out to MAC_N:

```
DECLARE @sColMac varchar(MAX);
DECLARE @iNumMac int;
SET @iNumMac = 1;
WHILE @iNumMac <= 5
    BEGIN
    SELECT @sColMac = COALESCE(@sColMac + ',', '') + QUOTENAME('MAC_' + CONVERT(varchar(10),@iNumMac))
    SET @iNumMac = @iNumMac + 1
    END

SELECT @sColMac
```

Comment: Can you scale it out for N number of MACs?

Comment: That would require dynamic sql. I've found it's best not to go that route because it becomes very difficult to debug (since everything must be written as a string). You could do something like what is appended in my edited answer, and just manually replace the two [MAC_N] strings.

Comment: @mikemorris That worked perfectly! I do have one question. If I wanted to scale it up, say an ID could have 4 MAC's and 4 SN's, and I wanted to have MAC_1, MAC_2, etc SN_1, SN_2, can the pivot function handle that or would it need to be two separate ones? Either way, this is exactly what I needed, thank you so much!

Comment: Yes, the PIVOT function could handle it, but the SELECT partition is not so flexible. In that case you'll have to do multiple SELECT partitions into a temporary table using UNION ALL. For example:
 SELECT * INTO #aggTable FROM
 (
[[SELECT PARTITION QUERY 1]]
UNION ALL
[[SELECT PARTITION QUERY 2]]
...
) as data

Then:

SELECT * FROM #aggTable
PIVOT (MAX(val) FOR namePivot in ([MAC_1],[SN_1], ...)
GROUP BY Id, [MAC_1], [SN_1], ...

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much! I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM

    (
    select case when x.COUNTID = 1 then 'MAC1' when x.COUNTID = 2 then 'MAC2' when x.COUNTID = 3 then 'MAC3' when x.COUNTID = 4 then 'MAC4' end MAC
            ,ID
            ,COUNTID
    from
        ( -- YOUR ORIGINAL (COUNT) QUERY-----
            select mac
                    ,ID
                    ,count(ID) COUNTID
            from YOUR_TABLE
            group by mac, ID
        ) x
    ) SRC
pivot(
    sum(COUNTID)
    for mac in ([MAC1], [MAC2], [MAC3], [MAC4])) piv
```